# Send an object by parameter to another function when I call it from a button

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, order-of-execution

I'm new in Javascript and I have some problems with the order of execution.

I have a search button that when I press it, I run the `Search()` function. In this function I process some data, which I save in the variable 'data'. However, I want to send those data as a parameter to the `other()` function, but when I run the HTML, first 'other' to 'search' is executed:

```
<div class="btn" onclick="selected()">Select</div>

...

<script>
  function selected(){
      data = some stuff...
  }
  other(data)
<script>
```

How can I make the function other to run only when I type `select` button?

I tried to do it this way but it doesn't work as it should:

```
<div class="btn" onclick="selected()">Select</div>

...

<script>
  function selected(){
      data = some stuff...
      other(data)
  }      
<script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This**

```js
  function selected(){
    var  data = document.getElementById("in").value;
    console.log(data);
    other(data);
      
  }      
function other(data1){
console.log(data1);

}
```

```html
<input type="text" style="padding:10px;width:100%" value="default" id="in">
<div class="btn" style="padding:10px; background:green;color:white;" onclick="selected()">Select</div>
```